# Command like "find" in Matlab

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Is there a command working exactly like [Matlab's `find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)?

I know that `Pick` might work, but I just want to give a logic condition to select the elements of a list instead of a particular value.

For instance:

```
T={a, b, c, d, e}
Ctl={2.3, 0, 5, 0, 0}
```

I'd like to pick the elements of `T` for which the corresponding element of `ctl` is greater than 0.

Comment: Yes, `Pick[]` is entirely appropriate: `Pick[T, Positive[Ctl]]`.

Comment: Thanks! And if I wanted to to know the position of the element of `Ctl` `>2`?

Comment: Replace `T` with `Range[Length[T]]`, or something like that...

Comment: Now that I think about it, `Position[]` is useful, too: `Position[Ctl, x_ /; x > 2]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the position/index within an array of all values in a specified interval, (like Matlab's find) using `Position`.  For instance:

```
pos = Position[a, _?((0.3 < # < 0.7) &)]
```

or

```
pos = Position[a, x_ /; (0.3 < x < 0.7)]
```

These find the indices of all elements in `a` with values between 0.3 and 0.7. The elements can be extracted from `a` using

```
Extract[a, pos]
```

For the requested example:

```
t = {a, b, c, d, e};
ctl = {2.3, 0, 5, 0, 0};
pos = Position[ctl, _?((# > 2) &)]
Extract[t, pos]

{{1}, {3}}
{a, c}
```

As suggested by J.M. in the comments, you can also use `Pick`:

```
Pick[t, Thread[ctl > 2]]
{a, c}
```

Answer (score 4):

You use a `PositionIndex` with `KeySelect` for this, which is a good approach if you need to use multiple tests against the same array.

```
In[1]:= T = {a, b, c, d, e}; 
        Ctl = {2.3, 0, 5, 0, 0};

In[2]:= index = PositionIndex[Ctl]
Out[2]= <|2.3 -> {1}, 0 -> {2, 4, 5}, 5 -> {3}|>

In[3]:= Extract[T, Values@KeySelect[index, Positive]]
Out[3]= {a, c}
```

Comment: Didn't know `PositionIndex`!

Comment: @Pillsy thank you for introducing `PositionIndex` to me +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for some ridiculousness (covering some of the give answers):

```
t = {a, b, c, d, e};
ctl = {2.3, 0, 5, 0, 0};
```

Various:

```
Pick[t, Positive@ctl] (* JM*)
Extract[t, Position[ctl, _?Positive]] (* bill s *)
Cases[Transpose[{t, ctl}], {x_, _?Positive} :> x]
First /@ Select[Transpose[{t, ctl}], #[[2]] > 0 &]
Last@Reap[Sow @@@ (Transpose@{t, ctl}), _?Positive, Sequence @@ #2 &]
True /. GroupBy[Transpose[{t, ctl}], Positive[#[[2]]] & -> First]
```